# GUI Program not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have been working on an app, where you set up a list of categories with items in it, which will then be made into a text file. But the GUI I've made for it doesn't work entirely. I think the error is situated in the JMenuItem called Cat (or "add category") or in the way I display the Categories (Update() method). It is supposed to ask for a name, make a Category named after that and display it in a JScrollPane, but nothing comes up. Here is the code:

```
public class GUIBuilder {
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel LeftPanel;
    public JPanel RightPanel;
    public JScrollPane scroll;
    public JMenuBar bar;
    public JMenu File;
    public JMenu Add;
    Inventory inv;

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        scroll = new JScrollPane();

        bar = new JMenuBar();
        File = new JMenu("File");
        Add = new JMenu("Add...");
        bar.add(File);
        bar.add(Add);

        JMenuItem Save = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Save") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        JMenuItem Load = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Load") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        JMenuItem Generate = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Generate Text File") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        File.add(Save);
        File.add(Load);
        File.add(Generate);

        JMenuItem Cat = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Add Category") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            JFrame Cat;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Cat = new JFrame("Add Category");
                final JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
                JButton Submit = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Submit") {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        String n = name .getText();
                        if (n != null) {
                            inv.addCategory(new Category(n));
                            pullThePlug();
                            GUIBuilder.this.Update();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Cat.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                Cat.add(name, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                Cat.add(Submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                Cat.setSize(250, 150);
                Cat.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void pullThePlug() {
                WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(Cat, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
            }
        });
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Add Item") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        Add.add(Cat);
        Add.add(item);

        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
        frame.setSize(500, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(scroll);

        inv = new Inventory();
    }

    public void Update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < inv.categories.size(); i++) {
            Category cat = inv.categories.get(i);
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JTextPane name = new JTextPane();
            name.setText(cat.getName());
            scroll.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What are `Inventory` and `Category` classes?

Comment: One tip: start small. Your code is very big if the GUI doesn't work at all. Start with a simple example, a small controlled code that you can reason about. So you'll learn how to assemble those small things to achieve what you want in an incremental way with working code.

Comment: Invventory is a class that stores the Categories, which store the Items themselves, which will be displayed in the gUI. And actually the only thing that doesn't work is the "Add Category" at the moment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your `JTextPane name` to your `JPanel p`.

(It also seems to me that you're missing a `main` method that will construct a `GUIBuilder` - but maybe that's in another file that you haven't shown in your question?)

---

Also, if you create an empty `JScrollPane`, you need to add components via `scrollpane.getViewport().add(yourcomponent);`.

You also need some layout management. The easiest way (and probably what you intended to do anyways) is:

```
    public void Update() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < inv.categories.size(); i++) {
            Category cat = inv.categories.get(i);
            JTextPane name = new JTextPane();
            p.add(name);        
            name.setText(cat.getName());                
        }
        scroll.getViewport().add(p);       
    }
```

Comment: Yes the main method is in another file and just calls go() ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah that was dumb. Thanks though ;)

Comment: Well, it still doesn't show anything even after adding the JTextPane

Comment: You're using `JScrollPane` wrong, see the new last paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to initialize `inv` before you show the `JFrame`.
Also you should swap the statements

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(scroll);
```

to

```
frame.add(scroll);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

So there's no repaint needed after adding your `JScrollpane`. Adding components while your component is already shown is quite tricky.
I really recommend you to end your method with `frame.setVisible(true);` or even extract this statement to an own method which gets called when `go()` finishes.
 ...Well, then it would be better to rename `go()` to `init()`, but thats another thing ;).  To divide constructing and showing frames is a good practice in my eyes.
**Edit:**
After rereading your code I can't see where your `JScrollpane` gets filled. Where do you add something to it?
Also you should read about the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) as attributes should't begin with a capital letter. This will improve you code's readability alot.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll try that. And the JScrollPane gets filled in the Update() method. And I didn't know about those conventions at all, so thanks again ;)